# AutoMapping Complex Structure

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm having difficulty mapping from;

```
File thisFile = repository.FindAll(x => x.FileId == fileId).SingleOrDefault();
//thisFile.FileContacts[x].Contact.Persons[n].FirstName;
```

the line commented above shows the path to the person's FirstName property

to;

```
public class FileSummary
    public List<PersonSummary> Contacts {get;set;}

public class PersonSummary
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
```

This

```
Mapper.CreateMap<File, FileSummary>().ForMember(x => x.Contacts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FileContacts));
```

doesn't work so well.

Comment: I'm not understanding what FileSummary and Contacts is, how does that relate to the first code sample you have there?

Answer (score 0):

If you write a test class and copy that mapping code, or simply call a method that includes the mapping, followed by

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

then you'll get an error report explaining what couldn't be mapped. This is how I generally start with my mapping.